Inference of distribution from sum of iid samples
Assume we observe $M$ samples $S_j$ of the sum of $N$ i.i.d. samples $X_i$ from a target distribution $p_X(x)$ (for which we cannot assume a parametric family but for which we can assume that it has only positive support), i.e.
$S_j = \sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$ .
The goal is to perform inference of the posterior $p(x|{S_1,...S_M})$.
I am experimenting with an MCMC approach using Metropolis-Hastings sampling. Due to the nature of the problem I have to propose N samples in each MCMC step. I have tried block-updates and component-wise updates for each of the N samples. I also tried an adaptive algorithm where for the block-update scheme, the covariance matrix of the multivariate Gaussian proposal distribution $q(\mathbf{x}^*|\mathbf{x})$ is nudged towards the covariance of accepted samples.
However, so far neither approach was successful.
Is MCMC the right approach here? Is this inference even feasible?
Edit: Clarified the question to cover the case of $M$ observed sums $S_j$.

By "observe the sum" do you mean you have a sample of such sums or do you mean you have exactly one such sum?  If it's the latter, you can't conclude anything useful at all about $p.$

Yes, indeed. My question targeted the case when I have exactly $M=1$ sample of the sum $S$. I edited the question to include the case of multiple observed samples of the sum. How about in this case? I assume one could use the Central Limit Theorem if $N$ was sufficiently large...

I don't see how, because the CLT goes in the wrong direction: suppose a large sample of $S$ looks Normally distributed.  About all you can infer concerning the original distribution are its mean and variance, but very little at all about its shape--because the CLT tells you the shape doesn't appreciably affect the distribution of $S$.
